# How to align CustomTkinter elements?

Tags: python, github, frontend, native, customtkinter

I was trying to create a simple application using CustomTkinter. The UI/UX is not very appealing as it is supposed to be a minor project. Very simply it will be converting image types.

When I am running the program, the **main** Python file that actually runs the whole app (I have deliberately named it **main.py**) the program runs but the widgets are placed in such a way that they are not properly displayed on the screen (on first program run, the window starts smaller than the full screen). This is the [image of the window at program start where the widgets cannot be seen properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGyBs.png).

Now the alignment was done completely using .place() function of the customtkinter.CTk() class to fix the UI to look good at full-screen. Here is the [image of the window on full screen where the widgets look more or less centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4g3y.png).

Now here is the code that was used. [Here we can see how the widgets were created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTTh8.png).

If anyone can help me positioning the widgets such that the widgets are centered even in the smaller screen (as in the **first image**), I would be grateful. Now please make sure, the widgets don't get distorted in the full screen window.

Me and 2 friends who are working on this project are continuously exploring and finding out how to do it but cannot find much help. So we had to come here for some help.

If anyone would like to contribute then this is the [GitHub repo of this project](https://github.com/mvp-2003/fformat)